# Pass additional data to fragment shader through VBO - DynamicSpriteBatch

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, andengine, vbo

I'm learning opengl shaders with AndEngine , my goal is to make DynamicSpriteBatch with some lightshader where light position will be passed throught vbo to each draw call in spritebatch so i can manipulate light source on every sprite.

So i have created  LightSpriteBatch ( with drawtype.dynamic )

```
public class LightSpriteBatch extends Shape {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final float[] VERTICES_TMP = new float[8];

private static final Transformation TRANSFORATION_TMP = new Transformation();

public static final int VERTEX_INDEX_X = 0;
public static final int VERTEX_INDEX_Y = 1;

public static final int COLOR_INDEX = 2;

public static final int TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_U = 3;
public static final int TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_V = 4;

public static final int LIGHT_POSITION_INDEX_X = 5;
public static final int LIGHT_POSITION_INDEX_Y = 6
        ;

public static final int VERTEX_SIZE = 2 + 1 + 2 + 2 ;
public static final int VERTICES_PER_SPRITE = 6;
public static final int SPRITE_SIZE = VERTEX_SIZE * VERTICES_PER_SPRITE;


public static final VertexBufferObjectAttributes VERTEXBUFFEROBJECTATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT = new VertexBufferObjectAttributesBuilder(4)
.add(ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION_LOCATION, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false)
.add(ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR_LOCATION, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR, 4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, true)
.add(ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES_LOCATION, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false)
.add(LightShader.ATTRIBUTE_LIGHT_POSITION_LOCATION, LightShader.ATTRIBUTE_LIGHT_POSITION, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false)
.build();
```

LightShader

```
public class LightShader extends ShaderProgram {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static LightShader INSTANCE;
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_LIGHT_POSITION = "a_lightPosition";
public final static int ATTRIBUTE_LIGHT_POSITION_LOCATION = 4;

public static final String VERTEXSHADER =
        "uniform mat4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTIONMATRIX + ";\n" +
        "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION + ";\n" +
        "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR + ";\n" +
        "attribute vec2 " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +
        "attribute vec2 " + LightShader.ATTRIBUTE_LIGHT_POSITION + ";\n" +
        "varying vec4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_COLOR + ";\n" +
        "varying vec2 " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +
        "varying vec2 v_lightPosition;\n" + 
        "void main() {\n" +
        " v_lightPosition = "+ LightShader.ATTRIBUTE_LIGHT_POSITION +" ;\n" +
        "   " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_COLOR + " = " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR + ";\n" +
        "   " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + " = " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +
        "   gl_Position = " + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTIONMATRIX + " * " + ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION + ";\n" +
        "}";




public static final String FRAGMENTSHADER =
        "precision lowp float;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D " + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_TEXTURE_0 + ";\n" +
        "varying lowp vec4 " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_COLOR + ";\n" +
        "varying mediump vec2 " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ";\n" +
        "varying lowp vec2 v_lightPosition;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        " vec4 tx = texture2D(" + ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_TEXTURE_0 + ", " + ShaderProgramConstants.VARYING_TEXTURECOORDINATES + ") ;"+
        " float u_radius = 100.0;"+
        " vec2 u_lightPosition = vec2(200-50+v_lightPosition.x,200-50+v_lightPosition.y);"+
        " float distance  = length( u_lightPosition - gl_FragCoord.xy );"+
        " float intensity =( 1.5-min( distance, u_radius )/u_radius)*1.5;"+ 
        " gl_FragColor = vec4(tx.r*intensity,tx.g*intensity,tx.b*intensity,tx.w);"+
        "}";

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

public static int sUniformModelViewPositionMatrixLocation = ShaderProgramConstants.LOCATION_INVALID;
public static int sUniformTexture0Location = ShaderProgramConstants.LOCATION_INVALID;

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

private LightShader() {
    super(LightShader.VERTEXSHADER, LightShader.FRAGMENTSHADER);
}

public static LightShader getInstance() {
    if(LightShader.INSTANCE == null) {
        LightShader.INSTANCE = new LightShader();
    }
    return LightShader.INSTANCE;
}

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

    @Override
protected void link(final GLState pGLState) throws ShaderProgramLinkException {
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(this.mProgramID, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION_LOCATION, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(this.mProgramID, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR_LOCATION, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_COLOR);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(this.mProgramID, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES_LOCATION, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURECOORDINATES);
    GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(this.mProgramID, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION_0_LOCATION, ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION_0);
    super.link(pGLState);

    LightShader.sUniformModelViewPositionMatrixLocation = this.getUniformLocation(ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTIONMATRIX);
    LightShader.sUniformTexture0Location = this.getUniformLocation(ShaderProgramConstants.UNIFORM_TEXTURE_0);
}

@Override
public void bind(final GLState pGLState, final VertexBufferObjectAttributes pVertexBufferObjectAttributes) {
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION_0_LOCATION);
    super.bind(pGLState, pVertexBufferObjectAttributes);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(LightShader.sUniformModelViewPositionMatrixLocation, 1, false, pGLState.getModelViewProjectionGLMatrix(), 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(LightShader.sUniformTexture0Location, 0);
}


    @Override
public void unbind(GLState pGLState) throws ShaderProgramException {
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(ShaderProgramConstants.ATTRIBUTE_POSITION_0_LOCATION);
    super.unbind(pGLState);
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
```

}

I have also created custom HighPerformanceLightSpriteBatchVBO where i'm passing light position into buffer

```
@Override
public void addWithPackedColor(final ITextureRegion pTextureRegion, final float pX1, final float pY1, final float pX2, final float pY2, final float pColorABGRPackedInt,final float pLightXX,final float pLightYY) {
    final float[] bufferData = this.getBufferData();
    final int bufferDataOffset = this.mBufferDataOffset;

    final float x1 = pX1;
    final float y1 = pY1;
    final float x2 = pX2;
    final float y2 = pY2;
    final float u = pTextureRegion.getU();
    final float v = pTextureRegion.getV();
    final float u2 = pTextureRegion.getU2();
    final float v2 = pTextureRegion.getV2();
    final float pLightX = pLightXX;
    final float pLightY = pLightYY;

    if(pTextureRegion.isRotated()) {
        bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_SIZE + LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = x1;
        bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_SIZE + LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = y1;
        bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_SIZE + LightSpriteBatch.COLOR_INDEX] = pColorABGRPackedInt;
        bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_SIZE + LightSpriteBatch.TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_U] = u;
        bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_SIZE + LightSpriteBatch.TEXTURECOORDINATES_INDEX_V] = v;
        bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_SIZE + LightSpriteBatch.LIGHT_POSITION_INDEX_X] = pLightX;
        bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * LightSpriteBatch.VERTEX_SIZE + LightSpriteBatch.LIGHT_POSITION_INDEX_Y] = pLightY;
```

with all of this it works but i have problems reading this lightposition in fragment shader. What calculations i need to do to properly calculate distance between light position and position if rendered texture ?

```
DynamicLightSpriteBatch sb = new DynamicLightSpriteBatch(mTextureSprite,10,getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        protected boolean onUpdateSpriteBatch() {
             draw(mTextureSpriteRegion, 0f, 0f, 400f, 400f, 0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,100f,100f); // ( 100,100 = lightX & Y ) 
            return true;
        }
    };
```

light is always at center (200-radius/2,200-radius/2) and it should be shifted by 100,100 as the last parameters

Comment: Could you post shader code as well?

Comment: There is ( second snippet from top ) LightShader

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly what you want is to have relative light position in fragment shader, which differs for each pixel. To do that, you need to access the modelview and projection matrices in vertex shader and calculate the `up` and `right` vectors for your sprite to be passed to fragment shader. Then in fragment shader add this (multiplied by the texcoord) to the sprite center position to get worldspace position of each shaded fragment (each pixel of the sprite). Subtract that from the light position and voila!

Note that in your shader code you seem to have a different precision specifiers for `varying` variables in vertex / fragment shaders. That may lead to problems (the varyings may not link, so that the value that is being output in vertex shader is thrown away and the input value in fragment shader is undefined). This is one of the dark corners of OpenGL, somewhat caused by the requirement to be able to arbitrarily mix and match different vertex and fragment shaders.